# Debian Squeeze can't install php-pear

Tags: debian, pear

I use Debian 6.0.6

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

results in:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.74) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
               Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.104) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
               Breaks: nfs-common (< 1:1.2.5-3) but 1:1.2.2-4squeeze2 is to be installed
 keyboard-configuration : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.71) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
 klibc-utils : Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.103) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Flagged to be moved to ServerFault as you will get better "on topic" responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running mixed distribution (stable/testing/etc) or using side repositories?

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libonig2 libqdbm14 php5-cli php5-common
Suggested packages:
  php5-dev
Recommended packages:
  php5-suhosin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libonig2 libqdbm14 php-pear php5-cli php5-common
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,167 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.

cat /etc/debian_version 
6.0.6
```

If this is the case, you should downgrade all non-mainstream package versions and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you did, but in case :

```
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install php-pear
```

try to execute commands in this order.

kinds